# What is the best way to send multiple data values through a socket?

Tags: java, android, sockets

so I have a Raspberry Pi that tracks a few temp sensor outputs and controls heaters to meet user defined setpoints. I'm now trying to create an app that talks with the pi so I can see the setpoints and actual temperature reading from my phone. In doing so, I was hoping to use a multicast so that I could eventually expand it to use more than one device. I want to eventually send a few pieces of information including a name for each device and the data values for the various sensors. I was kind of hoping that Java would have something I could send with a datagram packet that contains all of that info. I was thinking something similar to structs in C++ (This is one of my first attempts at Java), but I'm having trouble, since structs don't exist.

I could have a class that is entirely public, but I would then have to send that through the datagram, which seems pretty strange. Is there a better way to do this in Java?

I don't really have code to post, since this is sort of a design issue, but any code samples illustrating possible solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your help!

Edit: I should add that while I am writing this for android right now, I intend to do a similar thing on a PC.. I'm not sure how they differ or if they even would in this case, but I figured I'd throw it out there.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `DataOutputStream` and its primitive-writing methods in conjunction with a `ByteArrayOutputStream,` and wrap the bytes of he latter in a `DatagramPacket.` At the receiver, do the converse.

Comment: Ok, so I understand how to write to the 'DataOutputStream', but I'm a little bit fuzzy on how to use 'ByteArrayOutputStream' Does it literally just put the data in the output stream in byte format? From there I understand the 'DatagramPacket' side of things. In terms of reading it out on the other side, I guess there's no real way to know which numbers are which..I was thinking maybe as a solution to that issue using a hashmap and 'ObjectOutputStream' and sending that in a Datagram. Is that possible? Does that make sense for better organization?

Comment: You can do that. When you've finished writing, call `ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()` to get the byte array for the `DatagramPacket.`